# How to get notified about firmware upgrades?

Tags: upgrade, notification, firmware

I'm lucky enough to have found a laptop that can use the Linux firmware updating software (`fwupdmgr`). This is a Dell Latitude 5510, which according to the Linux-friendly salesperson is even certified for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Using ssh to connect to this machine gives me information I don't get anywhere else, like this:

```
~$ ssh puta
Welcome to Ubuntu 21.04 (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-31-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

1 device has a firmware upgrade available.
Run `fwupdmgr get-upgrades` for more information.

0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

I'm referring to the `fwupdmgr` message. Correctly enough, there was a firmware upgrade available for that machine, so an install and a reboot was required, as per the instructions there. I'm just puzzled I needed to use ssh to get that information in the first place. Maybe the call to fwupdmgr is something I should do on a regular basis... Do someone know how I can get this information automatically? A notification would be great!

Comment: The command that displays the `fwupdmgr` message probably gets called from one of the profile files (`/etc/profile`, `.profile` or `.bash_profile`). If you can find the correct command in the file, you can add it for example, to your "Startup Applications" so it will be run whenever you login to GUI desktop.

Comment: @raj Sorry, nothing to be found in any of these places.

Comment: As I watch closely the message on SSH login, it is displayed before profile runs, so I was wrong. This message is displayed by sshd from file `/run/motd.dynamic`, but I have yet to check what generates this file.

Comment: I found it in man pages: "Executable scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/*` are executed by `pam_motd(8)` as the root user at each  login,  and  this  information  is  concatenated in `/run/motd.dynamic`". So look into that directory and you should find your script there.

Comment: Also try `man fwupdmgr` (I just did it), it can give you some hints!

Comment: @raj – I'm a slow learner, but I'll get there eventually. Great hints :)